# Check what files are in a directory using js in .html file

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems, requirejs

I am trying to figure out how to read what how many/what files are located within '../mydirectory/images' in a .html file that I have that is the landing page for my website. I need this so I can automatically change some aspects of my website, based on how many images are located within that directory. I am very new to web development but have done some research and it seems like require.js would be the tool to use for this, but I am getting an error saying require isn't defined when trying to access the file system.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = '../mydirectory/images';

fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(files);
  }
});
```

Comment: You cannot access the file system from JavaScript code running in a web browser. It sounds like you're talking about work that needs to be done by your *server* software.

Answer (score 1):

[`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) is a module built into Node.js. It will not run in a browser. It is not suitable for your needs.

[Require.js](https://requirejs.org/) is a library for handling AMD modules in the browser. Node.JS uses, by default, CommonJS modules not AMD modules (but `fs` can't be used in the browser anyway as it is a *built-in* module). It is not suitable for your needs.

While your HTTP server may care about the layout of the file system when working out what response to give when a URL is requested, the browser only knows about URLs.

HTTP does not include any features designed for exploring file systems.

For your client-side code to get a directory listing, **first** the server needs to provide a URL which gives that listing.

Your HTTP server might have a built-in feature that does that (such as Apache HTTPD's [Directory Listing feature](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/DirectoryListings), but you might also consider writing some server-side code that presents the data in a format (such as JSON) which is easier to process client side.

**Second**, the client-side code needs to get that listing, perhaps using [the `fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and parse the URLs that are in it.

That said, it is quite likely that your broader problem would be better addressed using server-side (and not client-side) code in the first place.